# cloubuild unexpected characters '\'

Tags: bash, awk, google-cloud-build

```sh
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/blah/app | grep prod | head -n 1 | awk '{print \$2}' | cut -d ',' -f 2 | awk -F. '{\$NF = \$NF + 1;} 1' | sed 's/ /./g' > version.txt
```

I ran this with locally with docker and the cloudbuild image

`bash -c "gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/blah/app | grep prod | head -n 1 | awk '{print \$2}' | cut -d ',' -f 2 | awk -F. '{\$NF = \$NF + 1;} 1' | sed 's/ /./g' > version.txt"`

and it works. But when I send it to cloudbuild I got

```
awk: 1: unexpected character '\'
awk: 1: unexpected character '\'
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near =
```

Comment: Try to use `$$` instead of single `$` in your command.

Answer (score 0):

just using $$ is not enough. you need to remove the / also. this is what worked for me:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/blah/app | grep prod | head -n 1 | awk '{print $$2}' | cut -d ',' -f 2 | awk -F. '{$$NF = $$NF + 1;} 1' | sed 's/ /./g' > version.txt
```